# Replace a RegEx substring in a string (in Pine Script)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How can I use RegEx to replace a character (or substring) in a string?

I would like to remove a comma, but only if it is the last character of a string.

I know about the 'str.replace_all' instruction, but it does not seem to support RegEx:

`str.replace_all(my_string, ",$", "")`

Thank you!

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pinescript` does not support RegEx but you can use the built-in `array.x` and `string.x` functions to do what you want to do.

Here is an example:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

f_str_remove_last_char(str, c) =>
    string retval = str
    string[] chars = str.split(str, "")
    int len = array.size(chars)
    string[] sub_str = array.new_string(0)
    
    // Check the last char
    if (array.get(chars, len-1) == c)
        sub_str := array.slice(chars, 0, len-1)
        retval := array.join(sub_str, "")
    
    retval

str1 = ",str"
str2 = "s,tr"
str3 = "str,"

_str1 = f_str_remove_last_char(str1, ',')
_str2 = f_str_remove_last_char(str2, ',')
_str3 = f_str_remove_last_char(str3, ',')

if barstate.islast
    s = _str1 + '\n' + _str2 + '\n' + _str3
    label.new(bar_index, high, s)
```

[image]

[This](https://www.tradingview.com/script/l0wdrsUO-String-Manipulation-Framework-PineCoders-FAQ/) is a link to the string manipulation framework where you can see some other examples.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is wrong, there is support for regular expressions in PineScript since the [December 2021 update](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/fr/new-in-pine-overloads-new-string-functions-and-more-28453/). However, currently, only the [str.match](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_str%7Bdot%7Dmatch) function supports regex.

So this means you cannot directly replace using regular expression for matching.

So there are two alternative approaches using regex:

1. Either instead match what you want to keep, instead of trying to find something you want to remove.
2. Either use regex to match the comma you want to remove, and if the returned string is not empty, then you know that indeed there is a comma at the end of the string, so you can manually shorten the string.

For solution 2, it would be something like this (not tested, in particular I'm not sure what str.match returns when the regex does not match, the docs don't specify):

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

inputstr = "Some random sentence,"
result = str.match(inputstr, ",$") ? str.substr(inputstr, 0, str.length(inputstr) - 1) : ""
```

Lastly, you don't need regex for your purpose, nor even use arrays, if you just want to detect whether there is a comma at the end of the sentence, just use:

```
(str.pos(inputstr, ",") == str.length(inputstr) - 1) ? ...
```